IIS rule redirect url query parameter
Is it possible to use URL Rewrite to provide more complex query string functionality than the "Append query string" checkbox that it has? Specifically, is it possible to have different query string value? In this example I am trying to change 1503 to 1545
<rule name="Redirect_1503" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="https://demo.cars.com/car/cars-detail?category=2&amp;id=1503" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://demo.cars.com/car/cars-detail?category=2&amp;id=1545" />
</rule>


Yes. But It’s just a regular expression based rewrite engine, so you probably don’t try too complicated rules. BTW, avoid common mistakes, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59
